# Debugging socket server code

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, sockets, visual-c++

I am trying to step through the code of a program I didn't write (I have the source). It is a small http server. I am able to place breakpoints and they will be respected at any point that is run in a linear path from the `main()`. However, when I try to place a breakpoint at a line that gets called in response to a connection from the browser, it is just ignored.

Is there something I don't know about debugging socket code? I really don't know much about socket programming, but that is not the part that I am trying to see.

This is with Visual C++ 2010.

**EDIT**
I found the problem. There was a deeply nested call to `system` which was actually running the program again with different parameters. So it is not a thread or socket or whatever, it is actually a whole new child process. Is there any way to have the debugger continue into this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1**

Change your "system" call to pass a "--waitfordebugger" parameter to the child process.  Then in main or WinMain, check the command line args passed for this argument. If detected, make your code get into an infinite loop.

```
volatile int x = false;
while (x == false)
{
    Sleep(100);
}
```

When your child process is spawned, use Visual Studio to "attach" to the child process (Top level menu, select "Debug" and "Attach To Process..."). Then set a break point on the Sleep statement.  When the breakpoint is hit (should be immediate), change "x" in the watch window to true, set your new breakpoint to the place in the code you want to step through.  Then press the "continue" (F5) key for the program to carry on.

There are other variations of this technique including use of waiting until the IsDebuggerPresent() API returns TRUE.

**Option 2**

Near the place in the code you want to debug, insert a DebugBreak() statement. This will usually create crash dialog to pop open.  If it prompts you to attach a debugger, let it. Otherwise, just attach the debugger directly as described in Option 1 and then press the appropriate button on the crash dialog to continue. YMMV on this approach depending on what type of exception handlers have already been installed and/or if the system function call is setup to hide crashes.